# How to apply custom styles to a jasper html report

Tags: java, css, gwt, jasper-reports, ireport

How does one apply custom CSS to a HTML report generated using Jasper. I need to include this report as an iFrame into a GWT window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply include a link tag in your GWT html file like so:

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="myJasperStyles.css">`

The CSS file should explicitly refer to Jasper-related HTML tags to ensure the CSS won't affect your GWT elements.

Comment: AFAIK, the iFrame loads asynchronously. Will the styles get reflected in the iframe if the link tag is present in the parent file?

Comment: Yes, there should be no issue there.